# Unable to open Plugins Manager in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to open JMeter plugins manager but I am getting exception due to proxy restrictions. I tried the method to open Plugin manager using the method mentioned in the plugins manager page, but getting the following error from command prompt:

'JVM' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Is there anyother way I can configure it so that I can access the Plugins manager?

Comment: Thanks for your question! It looks like the JVM is not on the Windows Path. The Windows Path is the standard list of programs known to Windows from all folders, no matter where you are on the file system. Look online for ways to add JVM to the Path!

Comment: I have set the Environment variable already but still I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. I have added the following tags in `system.properties` file of JMeter:

```
http.proxyHost=IP address or hostname of your proxy server
https.proxyHost=IP address or hostname of your proxy server
http.proxyPort=port of your proxy server
https.proxyPort=port of your proxy server
http.proxyDomain=Domain for you User and password
https.proxyDomain=Domain for you User and password
```

For properties reference, I found the following link:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#proxy_config

Goto Topic 19.20 for Domain tag.

After this I started jmeter in command prompt along with parameter `-u` for username and `-a` for password. I am now able to open the Plugin Manager.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Plugins Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/#Plugins-Manager-Network-Configuration) -> [Using Behind the Proxy](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/#Using-Behind-the-Proxy)

> [Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager) respects [JMeter's proxy settings](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).

so add the next lines to *[system.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/system.properties)* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

```
http.proxyHost=IP address or hostname of your proxy server
https.proxyHost=IP address or hostname of your proxy server
http.proxyPort=port of your proxy server
https.proxyPort=port of your proxy server
```

once done restart JMeter to pick up the changes - you should be able to use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers via your corporate proxy and the Plugins Manager should be able to establish connectivity with the plugins repository as well.

More information:

- [Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Comment: I tried the above but I still am unable to connect to the respository from the plugins manager. Still getting the message "Failed to download Plugins repository"

Comment: What does *jmeter.log* file say?

Comment: Response with code HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: So you need to add `-Dhttp.proxyUser=your_username` and `-Dhttp.proxyPassword=your_password`

Comment: I already tried using the tags '-Dhttp.proxyUser','http.proxyUser' and 'https.proxyUser' but still getting the same error from Plugin Manager.

Comment: I have found a solution. Thanks for your help